# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Tags: apex, unit-test, error

I have a test class that was running fine until .  Now I continue to get this error message:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 001U000001grFRK: [] 
>   Stack Trace: Class.CSAssignNewPUCCTest.testCSAssignNewPUCC: line 205, column 1

Here is my test class snippet

```
 cppUserProfileID = [Select Id From Profile Where Name =: CPP_PARTNER_USer].Id;
 //creating cpp partner user for old user. 
 oldPartnerUser = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestUser(2, cppUserProfileID);
 oldPartnerUser.contactId = contactsList.get(1).Id;
 //  oldPartnerUser.UserRoleId = urole.Id;
 insert oldPartnerUser;

 System.runAs(oldPartnerUser) {
    acc = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestAccount(1);
        acc.Vertical_Markets__c = 'Carrier';
        acc.ownerId = oldPartnerUser.Id;
    insert acc;
    AccountTeamMember atmForPAM = new AccountTeamMember(AccountId = acc.Id,
        TeamMemberRole = 'Partner Account Manager', UserId = sysadminuser1.Id);
        //insert atmForPAM;
    con = CSTestDataBuilder.buildTestContact(5);
        con.AccountId = acc.Id;
        con.Email = 'testcon5@domain.com';
        con.ownerId = oldPartnerUser.Id;
    insert con;
```

The same code i have in another sandbox called UAT. In UAT this is working fine. Why it is not working in one sandbox. Can you please suggest me where could be the problem

Comment: I think the account acc you created is not accessible to the oldParternUser. You might want to create an account team member rec for acc & oldPartnerUser. Then this error will be resolved and you will be able to insert the contact.

Comment: What about record level access

Comment: Before you create the contact try querying out the account based on its ID. If it is working, then my approach is wrong.

Comment: Hi, Try removing the  line "acc.ownerId = oldPartnerUser.Id;" and "con.ownerId = oldPartnerUser.Id;" from the code and try to execute the code...

Comment: @chris You are getting "insufficient access" on an account record - So from your code snippet am guessing that the account named "acc" which you have inserted in your code is the one in which you are having insufficient access on. So I have a feeling that this account is not visible to you - hence I asked you to try querying this account in the code before you actually use it. If the query returns the account then the account is accessible and we need to think differently. Hope it makes sense. Thanks